# SignInPage does not see Username and password

Tags: wicket

I tried to implement a login using ServletContainerAuthenticatedWebApplication and registering the default SignInPage from Wicket as a sign in page. So far everything works, it redirects me to the login page when I try to access a protected resource, but I cannot login because the username and password fields inside SignInPanel are always null, regardless of what I enter in those inputs in the browser. I tried this with both Wicket 8.0.0-M8 and Wicket 7.9.0. Some help would be appreciated at this time.

```
    public class HelloWorldApplication extends ServletContainerAuthenticatedWebApplication
{
    private static String EJB_PROJ_NAME = "rezerva_masa_ejb";

    public HelloWorldApplication()
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void init()
    {
        super.init();
        getComponentInstantiationListeners().add(new JavaEEComponentInjector(this, new AppJndiNamingStrategy(EJB_PROJ_NAME)));
    }   

    @Override
    public Class getHomePage()
    {
        return HelloWorld.class;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<? extends ServletContainerAuthenticatedWebSession> getContainerManagedWebSessionClass()
    {
        return ServletContainerAuthenticatedWebSession.class;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<? extends WebPage> getSignInPageClass()
    {
        return SignInPage.class;
    }
}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>RezervaMasa</display-name>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>HelloWorldApplication</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
          <param-name>applicationClassName</param-name>
          <param-value>ro.rezervamasa.main.HelloWorldApplication</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>HelloWorldApplication</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>  
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>configuration</param-name>
        <param-value>development<!-- deployment --></param-value>
    </context-param>

    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <realm-name>ApplicationRealm</realm-name>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/login.html</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/login.html</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>

    <security-role>
        <role-name>view_users</role-name>
    </security-role>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>create_users</role-name>
    </security-role>

    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>All pages</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>view_users</role-name>
            <role-name>create_users</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
</web-app>
```

Comment: It look like you have problem with your model. Could you share that signinPanel code also .

Comment: The signInPanel is the one implemented by default by Wicket as a login page. Not sure if I can share links here but this is the code at github for it: https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/master/wicket-auth-roles/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/authroles/authentication/panel/SignInPanel.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why I had this problem. The next day I started the server again and everything worked fine. I think there was some publishing problem maybe.